# How to solve this optimisation problem for $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$ using Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, economics

I am attempting the following optimization problem, to yield $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$ in terms of $p$ and $u$. Although I cannot seem to get to the solution outlined below, what I believe should be a simple algebraic exercise has left me with pages of workings and no result. I would appreciate some guidance on the logic and order of operations here.

My approach so far has been to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the first two equations and then substitute into the final equation, although I am constantly left with an expression of $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$.

[image]

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: How to arrive at the expressions for x1* and x2* as outlined at the bottom of the question

Comment: Feel free to ask if you still have a question. If not, a reply is welcomed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first tw0 partial derivatives we have the following two equations:

$$p_1=\lambda\cdot \alpha k\cdot \left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^{1-\alpha}\Rightarrow p_1=\lambda\cdot \alpha\cdot  k\cdot x_2^{1-\alpha}\cdot x_1^{\alpha-1}$$

$$p_2=\lambda\cdot (1-\alpha) k\cdot \left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^{\alpha}\Rightarrow p_2=\lambda\cdot (1-\alpha)\cdot  k\cdot x_1^{\alpha}\cdot x_2^{-\alpha}$$

Dividing the first equation by the second equation. $\lambda$ and $k$ are cancelled out directly.

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{\alpha\cdot  x_2^{1-\alpha}\cdot x_1^{\alpha-1}}{(1-\alpha)\cdot   x_1^{\alpha}\cdot x_2^{-\alpha}}$$

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\cdot \frac{  x_1^{\alpha-1}}{  x_1^{\alpha}}\cdot \frac{ x_2^{1-\alpha}}{  x_2^{-\alpha}}$$

Using exponent-rules

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\cdot \frac{  x_2}{  x_1}\Rightarrow x_2=\frac{p_1}{p_2}\cdot \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\cdot x_1$$

Input the expression for $x_2$ into the third FOC (first order condition).

$$\overline u=k\cdot x_1^{\alpha}\cdot \left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\cdot \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\cdot x_1\right)^{1-\alpha}$$

$$\overline u=k\cdot x_1^{\alpha}\cdot \left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\cdot \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha}\cdot x_1^{1-\alpha}$$

$x_1^{\alpha}\cdot x_1^{1-\alpha}=x_1$

$$\overline u=k\cdot \left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\cdot \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha}\cdot x_1$$

We can write the term in the brackets at the LHS by swapping the numerators and the denominators.

$$\overline u\cdot \left(\frac{p_2}{p_1}\cdot \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha} =k\cdot x_1$$

$$x_1^*=\frac{\overline u}k\cdot \left(\frac{p_2}{p_1}\cdot \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Comment: You´re welcome.